# Django API + Android

Tags: python, android, api, django

Здравствуйте ХэшКодеры!
Хочу сделать клиент-приложение под Android для Django проекта, направьте в нужное русло, я понимаю что нужно разработать API, подойдет ли [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) для таких целей или вообще все по-другому это реализуется?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что будет на стороне сервера, вообще не имеет значение.
главное, что бы он отдавал в удобном формате клиенту , например json/xml

и да, django-rest-framework подойдет